# Convert from Swift 1.2 to 2 - variable function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm trying to add PNChart to my Swift 2.0 application.
I have a function and I want to convert it to 2.0, but I keep getting errors.

in swift 1.2

```
actualData.getData = {(index: NSInteger) -> PNLineChartDataItem in
    var yValue:CGFloat = array[index]
    var item = PNLineChartDataItem(y: yValue)
    return item
}
```

in objective-c

```
actualData.getData = ^(NSUInteger index) {
    NSNumber* value = array[index];
    CGFloat yValue = [value longValue];
    return [PNLineChartDataItem dataItemWithY:yValue];
};
```

in Swift 2.0 I get the error

```
Cannot assign a value of type ((NSInteger) -> PNLineChartDataItem) to a value of type LCLineChartDataGetter!
```

Comment: How is `LCLineChartDataGetter ` defined? Does it have the same signature as your closure?

Comment: From PNChart -> `typedef PNLineChartDataItem *(^LCLineChartDataGetter)(NSUInteger item);`

Answer (score 2):

Your `LCLineChartDataGetter` is defined as:

```
typedef PNLineChartDataItem *(^LCLineChartDataGetter)(NSUInteger item);
```

(note the `U` in `NSUInteger`)

Whereas you pass it an `NSInteger`. Change `NSInteger` to `NSUInteger` and it should work.

Also in Swift you can simplify the closure's head from this:

```
actualData.getData = {(index: NSUInteger) -> PNLineChartDataItem in
    // ...
    return item
}
```

To this and have it deduce the types:

```
actualData.getData = {index in
    // ...
    return item
}
```

Or the even replace the entire closure with this and let Swift do the magic for you:

```
actualData.getData = { PNLineChartDataItem(y: array[$0]) }
```